# String replace with recursive dictionary values

Tags: c#, dictionary, recursion

I have config for all the root api urls in app.config file that is loaded into dictionary of key and value pair.

```
Dictionary<string, string> variables = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "clientRefUrl", "[clientBaseUrl]/RealtimeReferenceData"},     
        { "clientRealtimeUrl", "[clientBaseUrl]/RealtimeClinicalData"},
        { "localApiUrl", "LocalApi/Generic"},
        { "integrationRootFolder", "C:\\LocalServer\\Integration"},
        { "clientBaseUrl", "https://company.com/api"},
        { "clientAuthBaseUrl", "https://auth.company.com/api"}
    };
```

I have an api url that comes from the config file like `<endpoint name="saveuser" address="[clientRefUrl]/SaveUser" />`.

I want to build that url in c# code as `https://company.com/api/RealtimeReferenceData/SaveUser`.

I am able to do this using the following method but the problem is that client has to make sure they don't move the `clientBaseUrl` to the top of the list. Or, any dependent key to the top of the list.

```
public static string EvaluateStringWithVariables(string strExpr)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> variables = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "clientRefUrl", "[clientBaseUrl]/RealtimeReferenceData"},     
        { "clientRealtimeUrl", "[clientBaseUrl]/RealtimeClinicalData"},
        { "localApiUrl", "LocalApi/Generic"},
        { "integrationRootFolder", "C:\\LocalServer\\Integration"},
        { "clientBaseUrl", "https://company.com/api"},
        { "clientAuthBaseUrl", "https://auth.company.com/api"}
    };

    foreach (string variable in variables.Keys)
    {
        var pattern = @"\[" + variable + @"\]";
        strExpr = Regex.Replace(strExpr, pattern, variables[variable]);
    }

    return strExpr;
}
```

Is there a better way to do the same without any restriction. I tried another solution that uses regex and recursion:

```
public static string EvaluateStringWithVariables(string strExpr)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> variables = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "clientRefUrl", "[clientBaseUrl]/RealtimeReferenceData"},     
        { "clientRealtimeUrl", "[clientBaseUrl]/RealtimeClinicalData"},
        { "localApiUrl", "LocalApi/Generic"},
        { "integrationRootFolder", "C:\\LocalServer\\Integration"},
        { "clientBaseUrl", "https://company.com/api"},
        { "clientAuthBaseUrl", "https://auth.company.com/api"}
    };

    Regex regEx = new Regex(@"\[(\w+)\]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    strExpr = regEx.Replace(strExpr, match =>
    {
        string val = String.Empty;
        if (variables.TryGetValue(match.Groups[1].Value, out val))
        {
            return val;
        }
        return match.Value;
    });

    Match rmatch = regEx.Match(strExpr);
    if (rmatch.Success)
    {
        return EvaluateStringWithVariables(strExpr);
    }

    return strExpr;
}
```

But, recursion didn't go well when I had to evaluate a string like:
`strExpr = "[integrationRootFolder]\\myfolder\\[msg.ClientId]\\In\\[personid]_[tabid]_[documentname]_[msg.ClientId].pdf";` which keep on trying to evaluate other variables that is not part of dictionary.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered, you should not trust that your `foreach` will keep the order even if your user does not reset the order. Also, I don't see what problem you had with the regex solution, of course it is going to test stuff that is not in the dictionary, the whole point of dictionaries is that they are fast to test. You just need to keep matching till you run through the program and `variables.TryGetValue` never returns true.

Comment: Yes @ScottChamberlain, that is another problem in hand. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your regex solution was quite close, you just need to check to see if you found any values in the dictionary when you did the replace and if you did then call it recursively.

```
public static string EvaluateStringWithVariables(string strExpr)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> variables = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "clientRefUrl", "[clientBaseUrl]/RealtimeReferenceData"},     
        { "clientRealtimeUrl", "[clientBaseUrl]/RealtimeClinicalData"},
        { "localApiUrl", "LocalApi/Generic"},
        { "integrationRootFolder", "C:\\LocalServer\\Integration"},
        { "clientBaseUrl", "https://company.com/api"},
        { "clientAuthBaseUrl", "https://auth.company.com/api"}
    };

    Regex regEx = new Regex(@"\[(\w+)\]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    bool foundMatch = false;
    strExpr = regEx.Replace(strExpr, match =>
    {
        string val = String.Empty;
        if (variables.TryGetValue(match.Groups[1].Value, out val))
        {
            foundMatch = true;
            return val;
        }
        return match.Value;
    });

    Match rmatch = regEx.Match(strExpr);
    if (rmatch.Success && foundMatch )
    {
        return EvaluateStringWithVariables(strExpr);
    }

    return strExpr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a quick but a suboptimal solution/fix for your first approach.

```
string prev;
do {
 prev = strExpr;
 foreach (string variable in variables.Keys)
    {
        var pattern = @"\[" + variable + @"\]";
        strExpr = Regex.Replace(strExpr, pattern, variables[variable]);
    }
}
until (prev == strExpr);
```

It will repeat substitutions until there's no replacements in the string.
You should care about possible loops in your substitution definitions. If there's any, do-loop will never ends. Add necessary checks or limit repetition count.